# Getting session from another Servlet

Tags: java, session, servlets

I'm trying to store a User object in session in Servlet1. In Servlet2 I'm trying to get the values from the same logged in session from Servlet1.

Servlet1:

```
private void login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    String emailFromForm = request.getParameter("email").toLowerCase();
    String passwordFromForm = request.getParameter("passWord");

    try {
        User userThatLogsIn = manager.getUser(emailFromForm);
        String passwordFromDB = userThatLogsIn.getPassword();

        if (passwordFromDB.equals(passwordFromForm)) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("TheLoggedInUser", userThatLogsIn);
            response.sendRedirect("/Slit/welcome.jsp");
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("error", "Unknown login, try again");
            response.sendRedirect("/Slit/LoginFailed.jsp");
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException nullPointer) {
        System.err.println("NullPointerException: " + nullPointer.getMessage());
        response.sendRedirect("/Slit/LoginFailed.jsp");
    }
}
```

Servlet2:  Im getting a nullpointer sessionaccept fnavn
at Mypage.MyPageServlet.sessionAccept(MyPageServlet.java:40)

```
private void sessionAccept(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(30 * 60);
    User loggedInUser = (User) request.getAttribute("TheLoggedInUser");
    String fnavn = loggedInUser.getfName();
    String enavn = loggedInUser.getlName();
    String epost = loggedInUser.getEmail();


    request.getSession().setAttribute("messageJSP", "Velkommen" + epost);
    response.sendRedirect("Innstillinger.jsp");

}
```

Comment: in first servlet you have `request.getSession().setAttribute("TheLoggedInUser", userThatLogsIn);` . So if you want to use the `userThatLogsIn` this value in second servlet, then do like this. `request.getSession().getAttribute("TheLoggedInUser");`  This line `User loggedInUser = (User) request.getAttribute("TheLoggedInUser");` has to replaced with `User loggedInUser = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("TheLoggedInUser");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
User loggedInUser = (User) request.getAttribute("TheLoggedInUser");
```

has to replaced with

```
User loggedInUser = (User) 
request.getSession().getAttribute("TheLoggedInUser");
```